# How can I make a file that can only be read by my application?

Tags: vb.net, file

I want to know if there's a way to create a file that only my application can read but other programs (eg: notepad) can't

For example:
 i create a config file from my application, and if i open it with notepad it will be garbled nonsense, like:

> ½ÁoLG0%­Ö9)9Ìm•~0ý<öKfƒ”ü9´~<ƒ\,Aëxzºv‡@u}ž¹ñ7µK³¨]fÛn    {ç›žÔºî*Ò\úÇƒ«E%ñ
>   x@ÂÃ‹¼†ZÜŸ¹>ÇðÏ•Þ¢dóü0¹ñS`|ÛV‰‡Fëm¬2°,üdVNÆ$å^Rf­¾!v¼ñ
>   ¡ýù´ÿËjC&¤œšÍÉ]ËÈFæTñq%#++ÜÝ[êq"@hbÍj‰Œ‚äd¡†¸<×sæå‘óùOÃ«\2rxy

Comment: Please read [Ask] and take the [Tour]

Comment: You should consider creating binary file, notepad can't read them, but you can't just create your own charset. Maybe try to encode it.

Comment: There are many things to consider... If your program code is not secure, securing the data like fort-knox is overkill. Also, if making your data so encrypted shackles your program by making it unreasonably slow than reasonable.. you have gone too far.  Generally a decent binary file with any important strings encrypted is sufficient. File should have some form of  checksum values though to limit injections.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for encryption, if you want something readable only to your application but not the end user.

I don't know `VB.NET` but a quick google search shows me [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987186/aes-encrypt-string-in-vb-net) which has a pretty well written answer, that seems to explain how to encrypt a file in VB.NET

Comment: That basically moves the problem to handling the encryption securely. That said encryption will improve the security by increasing the work factor.

Comment: Judging by the initial quality and specificity of the original question, I doubt that me writing up an entire thing about how to write a secure program is going to be worth anyones effort, he asked how to write a file only his program can read, this is the closest i can give him without getting way way too specific for the ideal of basic generalized QA this site seems to focus on.

Comment: I am not complaing about your answer, just augmenting it. Oftern developers new to encryption overlook that securing the key is hard or impossible. Note the second sentence in my comment.