# Expression expected {"=="} in vb

Tags: string, vb.net, base-class-library

So I copied an AES algorithm from this [AES Encrypt String in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987186/aes-encrypt-string-in-vb-net) I use the second answer but I have an error in the decryption part. It says expression expected `{"=="}` in the `Dim ivct = ciphertext.Split({"=="}, StringSplitOptions.None)` part. How do I solve this?

Comment: i tried it on 3.5, 4.0 and 4.6...option strict on and off...its valid syntax

Comment: can you solve my problem?

Comment: @Ctznkane525, it's not a .NET version issue but a VB version issue. What version of VB.NET are you using?  That code is valid in recent versions but in older ones you would need this: `Dim ivct = ciphertext.Split(New String() {"=="}, StringSplitOptions.None)`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney - can you elaborate on this...the version of vb would be tied to the framework...do you instead mean the version of visual studio?

Comment: "the version of vb would be tied to the framework". No it wouldn't. VB 2005 can target .NET 2.0, VB 2017 can target .NET 2.0 and so can every version of VB in between. The issue here is one of VB syntax, so it's a VB issue, not a .NET issue. As far as .NET is concerned, all it cares about is that the first argument passed to `String.Split` is a `String` array. What can validly represent a `String` array in code is wholly dependent on the VB version. The original code is valid in VB 2017 whether you're targeting .NET 2.0 or .NET 4.7.2 but it is never valid in VB 2005.

Comment: string.split requires a `char` type as the parameter. If you want to split the string using `==` as the delimiter, try `Dim ivct = Split(ciphertext, "==", StringSplitOptions.None)`. If you want to use "==" including quotes, try """==""" instead.