# Encryption: with vb.net I get a different result than php

Tags: php, vb.net, encryption, aes

I have this php code

```
$plain_text = "abc";
$salt = "123";
echo $encrypted_text = openssl_encrypt($plain_text, "AES-128-ECB", $salt);
// result: kR/1uaFarptS5+n951MVsQ==
```

I have tried several methods (classes and functions) on vb.net, but the result of the encryption with this language is everytime not the same as above using php.
For example this one:

```
Public Function AES_Encrypt (ByVal input As String, ByVal pass As String) As String
        Dim AES As New System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged
        Dim Hash_AES As New System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider
        Dim encrypted As String = ""
        Try
            Dim hash (31) As Byte
            Dim temp As Byte () = Hash_AES.ComputeHash (System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes (pass))
            Array.Copy (temp, 0, hash, 0, 16)
            Array.Copy (temp, 0, hash, 15, 16)
            AES.Key = hash
            AES.Mode = Security.Cryptography.CipherMode.ECB
            Dim DESEncrypter As System.Security.Cryptography.ICryptoTransform = AES.CreateEncryptor
            Dim Buffer As Byte () = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes (input)
            encrypted = Convert.ToBase64String (DESEncrypter.TransformFinalBlock (Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length))
            Return encrypted
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Function

 sEnc = AES_Encrypt("abc", "123")
 Console.WriteLine(sEnc)
'result: Z3hCHcS0b2zJ7fEod3jcrw==
```

Please, with vb.net (no C#), how can I get the result "kR/1uaFarptS5+n951MVsQ==" which encryption of the text "abc" and salt "123" using the algorithm "AES-128-ECB"?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987186/aes-encrypt-string-in-vb-net) help? Seems like your code is designed to give a different ciphertext everytime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the specification `AES-128-ECB` in the PHP code, AES-128 is used in ECB mode, i.e. the key is 16 bytes long. But since only a 3 bytes large key is applied (`123`), PHP pads to the necessary size of 16 bytes with `0x00` values. Note that if the key is too long, it will be truncated.

In the VB code a 32 bytes key is used. Since in .NET the keysize determines the AES variant, AES-256 is applied. Moreover, the passed key is not used directly, but the actual key is derived from the passed value with the digest MD5.

So that the VB code returns the result of the PHP code, the logic of the PHP code must be implemented in the VB code:

```
...
'Dim hash(31) As Byte
'Dim temp As Byte() = Hash_AES.ComputeHash(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(pass))
'Array.Copy(temp, 0, hash, 0, 16)
'Array.Copy(temp, 0, hash, 15, 16)
'AES.Key = hash
Dim keyPadded(15) As Byte
Dim key = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(pass)
Array.Copy(key, 0, keyPadded, 0, Math.Min(16, key.Length))
AES.Key = keyPadded
...
```

A few remarks:

- In the PHP code the key is called `$salt`. This is misleading, because a [salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) has a different meaning.
- The [ECB](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/20946) mode is generally insecure.
- [AES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard)-128 uses a 16 bytes key. `123` is not a strong key (but maybe this is just a dummy value).
- If `123` does not represent a key, but a password from which a key is derived, then in general you should not use MD5, but specially designed algorithms like [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) or [Argon2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon2), see also [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/34279).