# AES Encryption for Password Management System in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, encryption, cryptography, aes

I am working on a Password Management System in `VB.NET`. I am using `AES 256 CBC` to encrypt my data and access database file in which I am storing the data.

But I want to go little complex with it now.

I want to generate random encryption key for each records everytime user adds a new record and it will be stored in the `accdb` file for decrypting the data later.

How can I do this in `VB.NET`? Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Understand this is C# but the concepts, methods etc all carry over.  Probably as good a place to get started https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aes?view=net-5.0

Comment: @Hursey You can see the vb code by changing the drop down to the top of the page from C# to VB.

Comment: So, the question is How to "generate random encryption key". `GUID.NewGUID`

Comment: Also check [AES Encrypt String in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987186/aes-encrypt-string-in-vb-net)